# Tooltip icon before the word?

Tags: tooltips

Im working on an existing site, and the tooltip icon is before the word. I have never seen this before. Is this common? This looks like bad UX to me, but I don't want to make the argument to change it unless this is something that has been done before and I have not seen it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sabrina, can you offer a picture or a more detailed description? It is unclear by what you mean by "tooltip icon" and it being "before the word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the tooltip icon is a "?" in a circle, or similar implementation. I would agree that putting a "?" at the head of the label is improper design. Something to consider, as well, when designing a tooltip icon is to place it clear of the label on the right, and make it dissimilar in form from the label text, so as not to imply a question is being asked (nor needs to be asked).